# Changing ImageView source

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` with a source image set in the xml using the following syntax:

```xml
   <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/articleImg"
      style="@style/articleImgSmall_2"
      android:src="@drawable/default_m" />
```

Now I need to change this image programmatically. What I need to do is delete the old image and add a new one though. What I have done is this:

```java
myImgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.monkey);
```

It works but I noticed android stacks the new image on top of the old one (dont ask me how I found out it's not relevant for the discussion :). I definitely need to get rid of the old one before setting the new image.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 772, accepted):

### Changing ImageView source:

Using [`setBackgroundResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) method:

```
  myImgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.monkey);
```

you are putting that monkey in the background.

I suggest the use of [`setImageResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) method:

```
  myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey);
```

or with [`setImageDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method:

```
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey));
```

#### *** With new android API 22 `getResources().getDrawable()` is now deprecated. This is an example how to use now:

```
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
```

and how to validate for old API versions:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
   } else {
     myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey));
}
```

Comment: oh cool ...

unfortunately I have just found out that I need to also replace an image set with 

myImgView.setImageDrawable(img);

the code you suggested 

myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey);

is not able to do it. how can I get rid of the drawable before rendering the monkey? :)

many thanks

Comment: getDrawable(int) is now deprecated and getDrawable(int,theme) is added in API-21. Now what to do? Can you please update your answer?

Comment: Call requires API level 16 (current min is 13): `android.widget.ImageView`#setBackground

Comment: `ContextCompat` to get drawable without `getTheme`

Comment: Now, instead of `getResouces().getDrawable(...)`, use `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), ...)`.

Comment: Latest simply use yourImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, yourImage));

Answer (score 73):

You're supposed to use `setImageResource` instead of `setBackgroundResource`.

Comment: [Comparison of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221673/what-is-the-difference-between-imageview-setbackgroundresource-and-imageview-set)

Answer (score 36):

```
myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey);
```

is used for setting image in the current image view, but if want to delete this image 
then you can use this code like:

```
((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1)).setImageResource(0);
```

now this will delete the image from your image view, because it has set the resources value to zero.

Answer (score 22):

get ID of ImageView as

```
ImageView imgFp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFp);
```

then Use

```
imgFp.setImageResource(R.drawable.fpscan);
```

to set source image programatically instead from XML.

Answer (score 17):

### Supplemental visual answer

`ImageView`: `setImageResource()` (standard method, aspect ratio is kept)

[image]

`View`: `setBackgroundResource()` (image is stretched)

[image]

Both

[image]

My fuller answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685546/3681880).

Answer (score 13):

Or try this one. For me it's working fine:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, image));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set in imageview an image that is inside the **mipmap dirs** you can do it like this:

`myImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.my_picture)`

Answer (score 4):

**Just write a method for changing imageview**

```
public void setImage(final Context mContext, final ImageView imageView, int picture)
{
    if (mContext != null && imageView != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(picture, mContext.getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
            } else
            {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(picture));
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```