# What is the difference between ImageView.setBackgroundResource and ImageView.setImageResource?

Tags: android, image, background, imageview

I have seen these different approaches in setting images but I don't get the difference.

Why there two methods?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`setBackgroundResource` is for setting the background of an ImageView.
`setImageResource` is for setting the src image of the ImageView.
Given:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
```

Then:

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagedata);
```

Will fit the image for the entire background. That means it will stretch the image to fill that background entirely even if the image size is too small.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagedata);
```

Will occupy only the size of the image in ImageView.
For that you want to also set

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for your ImageView. If the size of the image is smaller than the ImageView the remaining border will be left blank and the background will be shown.

Comment: But do you need to set some padding or something ?

Comment: Set padding for what reason? Think of it as two layers: background is behind and the source acts as foreground. In case the image source in not transparent, you will not be able to see the background.

Comment: If you'd like a white border around the src image, you'd set padding of the imageview and set a white color as the background resource, for example. Otherwise there's no need for padding.

Answer (score 3):

SetBackdroundResource is for a drawable or color you want to set at the background of the  imageview and your setImageResource is like to display on it.

so setImageResource is for add any resource to your imageview's front side. try this example and look at the difference. [Android Gallery, ImageView Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example)
. This is a two layer effect,backside (setBackgroundResource) and frontside (setImageResource).

Comment: Your link to "androidpeople.com" is dead. But I can image what you mean by "two layer effect". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The method [`setBackgroundResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) belongs to all Views. The method [`setImageResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) only belongs to `ImageView`. You can set them both:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sky);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.balloons);
```

[image]

The `setBackgroundResource()` method will cause the image's width and height will be stretched to fill the size of the view. The `setImageResource()` method will let its image keep its aspect ratio.

My fuller answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685546/3681880).

Answer (score 0):

`setBackgroundResource` sets the background image of an ImageView. The XML attribute is: `android:background`

`setImageResource` sets the image displayed in an ImageView. The XML attribute is: `android:src`