# Change Image of ImageView programmatically in Android

Tags: android, imageview

When I change the image programmatically‎, it shows new image on top of the old image which is set originally in layout file?

Here is a snippet of my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qStatusImage"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/thumbs_down"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grp_child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/radio_colors"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:background="@color/grey"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

And the code that sets the imageView:

```
     @Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//Answers
            if(answersGroup != null)
                   answersGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                       @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                         //  int index = answersGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(answersGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

                           qImageView = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.qStatusImage);
                           if(ans ==0 || ans == 5){
                            //   qSV.setImageResource(0);
                               qImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbs_up);
                           }
                           else
                               qImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbs_down);

                       }
                   });
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

That happens because you're setting the src of the `ImageView` instead of the background.

Use this instead:

```
qImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thumbs_down);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7221673/1454261)'s a thread that talks about the differences between the two methods.

Comment: This doesn't work in API 14. Should use: `image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_dot1);`

Comment: @Brave's answer is correct.  Using `setBackgroundResource()` :( did not remove the existing image before using the new image.. so I got two images colliding there.  `setImageResource()` worked tho :).  Still .. the post got me on the right track - my thanks for both answers!

Comment: As the answer by @mricyicy says, the problem is that the xml is defining the background image and the code is changing the resource image. Those are not the same. Setting the resource image is what is actually desired here, so the xml should be fixed.

Comment: Why not `setImageResource`?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe `ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);` worked for me

Comment: @Brave's answer is more accurate.

Comment: As @MartinEpsz correctly notes, the XML is the incorrect part here - it's setting the background instead of the src.  This answer changes the Java to be incorrect in the same way that the XML is.  While this does remove the problem of two images on top of each other, it would be better to fix the XML to set the image via `android:src` instead.

Answer (score 102):

Use in XML:

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

Source use:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.your_image));
```

Answer (score 88):

### Short answer

Just copy an image into your `res/drawable` folder and use

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

### Details

The variety of answers can cause a little confusion. We have

- [`setBackgroundResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int))
- [`setBackgroundDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
- [`setBackground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
- [`setImageResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29)
- [`setImageDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
- [`setImageBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap))

The methods with `Background` in their name all belong to the `View` class, not to `ImageView` specifically. But since `ImageView` inherits from `View` you can use them, too. The methods with `Image` in their name belong specifically to `ImageView`.

The `View` methods all do the same thing as each other (though `setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated), so we will just focus on `setBackgroundResource()`. Similarly, the `ImageView` methods all do the same thing, so we will just focus on `setImageResource()`. The only difference between the methods is they type of parameter you pass in.

### Setup

Here is a `FrameLayout` that contains an `ImageView`. The `ImageView` initially doesn't have any image in it. (I only added the `FrameLayout` so that I could put a border around it. That way you can see the edge of the `ImageView`.)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below we will compare the different methods.

### setImageResource()

If you use ImageView's `setImageResource()`, then the image keeps its aspect ratio and is resized to fit. Here are two different image examples.

- `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sky);`
- `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.balloons);`

[image]

### setBackgroundResource()

Using View's `setBackgroundResource()`, on the other hand, causes the image resource to be stretched to fill the view.

- `imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sky);`
- `imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.balloons);`

[image]

### Both

The View's background image and the ImageView's image are drawn separately, so you can set them both.

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sky);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.balloons);
```

[image]

Comment: note the following about `setImageResource`: `Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.
This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(Drawable) or setImageBitmap(Bitmap) and android.graphics.BitmapFactory instead.`

Comment: goood explanation @Suragch

Answer (score 31):

```
qImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
```

I think this will help you

Answer (score 20):

**In XML Design**

```
android:background="@drawable/imagename 
android:src="@drawable/imagename"
```

**Drawable Image via code**

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);
```

**Server image**

```
  ## Dependency ##

  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

  Glide.with(context).load(url) .placeholder(R.drawable.image)
   .into(imageView);

 ## dependency  ##
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

 Picasso.with(context).load(url) .placeholder(R.drawable.image)
 .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 14):

In your XML for the image view, where you have `android:background="@drawable/thumbs_down`
change this to `android:src="@drawable/thumbs_down"`

Currently it is placing that image as the background to the view and not the actual image in it.

Answer (score 3):

If the above solutions are not working just delete this entire line from XML

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

& only try

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
val drawableCompat = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_emoticon_happy)
```

or in java java

```
Drawable drawableCompat = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_emoticon_happy)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, we can change ImageView programmatically like this.

```
ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);
```

In Kotlin,

```
val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working in my case:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo)
```