# Button click event to change image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick, buttonclick

Is there any method available for suppose if I click the button than the image should be change. Number of times I click the button the image should be change.

Comment: You can go through the images list or wherever the images are saved using a button click listener event.

for example: if you have a list containing images URLs you can start looping from the first position in the list which is index = 0, go on until you reach the last index, then go back to index 0.

Comment: You can create an integer that increment everytime you click the button then write an if statement based on the number of clicks then change the ImageView based on your condition.

Comment: @L2_Paver thats exactly what i did. I have used random number and switch case. The number of time i click the button one random number will be generated and based on that it will change the image of image view. But i dont know which method is used for button.
For suppose i want to change the image when i click the image than I have writtrn like this `myImageView.setDrawbleResource(R.drawble.imagename)`

Comment: @KhaledAlmanea I have taken a random number and switch case. Based on that numbers images must be changed. The number of times i click the button one random number will be generated and based on that it will change the image of imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to change the image of an `ImageView`

For changing the image of an `ImageView`, inside the `onClick()` of the `Button` use:

```java
myImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_image_name);
```

Here, `myImageView` is the object bound an `ImageView`, and
`R.drawable.my_image_name` is the location of the image file present in your `Drawable` folder.

For more details refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906528/change-image-of-imageview-programmatically-in-android) thread

**Update**

> I have use a random number and switch case. When I click the button the number will be generated and pass to switch case and based on that the image should appear in the image view.

In that case, let's assume you have `3` images in your `drawable` folder.
 You can use a HashMap where the `key` is the `index` and the `value` is the `image-path`

```java
HashMap<Integer, Integer> imageMap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
imageMap.put(1,R.drawable.my_image4);
imageMap.put(2,R.drawable.my_image3);
imageMap.put(3,R.drawable.my_image2);
```

Now, generate Random number in range `1-3`

```java
int min = 1;
int max = 3;
int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Finally, set the image at the randomly generated position.

```java
int randomImageId = imageMap.get(randomNumber);
myImageView.setBackgroundResource(randomImageId);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer...I want that when I click the button I want that image to be change

Comment: @MaitriPatel That's exactly what I answered. Add the above-provided code inside the `onClick()` function of your `button`

Comment: I have use a random number and switch case. When i click the button the number will be generated and pass to switch case and based on that the image should be appear in the image view.

Comment: @MaitriPatel I have updated the answer. Hope that solves your problem