# How to set ImageView Resource from Java Image data type in Android

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I am trying to set a Image View resource from a Image Data Type

Something like

```
//this line is not working
Image storeImage = new Image(R.drawable.butterfly);

ImageView mainImage = findViewById(R.id.mainImage);

//this line is not working either
mainImage.setImageResource(storeImage);
```

For my work

I need to store image in a variable
then use it later for Image view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Image of ImageView programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906528/change-image-of-imageview-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: no this doesn't, those are for direct image resources. I don't know why people calling duplicate without considering this properly

Comment: It is a duplicate .. The `Image` class you are trying to use is of `android.media` is has noting to do with resource. because your Image is in drawable folder so you should not be using `Image` .

Comment: but how it solves my problem because my problem is to store image file for later use. there is no mention to that. is there?

Comment: @ADM that dupe has an awwwwful accepted answer, it suggests setting the background rather than the image resource :-( https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685546/208273 from that question is the answer that the asker is looking for (it matches the accepted answer), but it's kinda buried.

Comment: Yeah @RyanM actually i found this question misleading .. it was all about saving `R.drawable.butterfly` in a variable not about `ImageView's` Src or background ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the drawable directly, to the view:

```
//store the id of the drawable
int image = R.drawable.butterfly

ImageView mainImage = findViewById(R.id.mainImage);

mainImage.setImageResource(image);
```

Comment: For my work.
I need to store Image in some kind of variable.
then use it with the imageView

Comment: Good, accept so others know the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your image is stored, once you added it to your Drawable resource folder.
You can access it with an ID which can be stored in a variable (datatype int):

```
int storeImage = R.drawable.butterfly;
```

Then you have to make your ImageView accessible as you already did:

```
ImageView mainImage = findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
```

Your code `mainImage.setImageResource(storeImage);` doesn't work because "storeImage" is an int, but the function expects a Drawable. Each time you want to convert the ID into a Drawable, you have to use `getDrawable(storeImage);`.

Therefore your whole code would look like this:

```
int storeImage = R.drawable.butterfly;
ImageView mainImage = findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
mainImage.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(storeImage));
```

Answer (score 0):

mainImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.butterfly));