# App shows black image on Image View instead of actual image at runtime

Tags: java, android

The ImageView fills with black color after setting an image.

I'm setting image with this line

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Root = findViewById(R.id.Iv);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Proximity = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

    //Root.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
   Root.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Please post your full code

Comment: Please review it

Comment: Here I'm using API level: 23

Comment: What the resolution of your image ? did you by any chance cover the ImageView by any other view

Comment: I have only one widget named ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mobile screen comes with different sizes, so may be your image resolution is high or not compatible to the width & height of ImageView. Try to decrease the size of image so that it loads on Runtime also.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
  Context mContext = this;
  Root.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a));
```

Comment: Please refer this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685546/12830957). May be this could help you