# Android Quizz App

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm using the following code below for an application.

I want to get `imageview` `i1` to appear on an other activity. How can I do this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);
    monwin = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mysound);
    monlose = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mywrong);
    bt1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd1);
    bt2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd2);
    i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c1);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bt1.isChecked()){
                i1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                monlose.start();
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, cant you write i1.bringToFront();

Comment: You cant simply ask a blank question without actually mentioning your problem. what do u mean by "Other activity"? Explain your question lil bit more. Post your xml code that will be helpful.

Comment: I want to sya that for example in Intent 1 i have an imageView that cannot be visible or not depending of a selection of a specifi c radio button.And when i go to the secod activity the image must be visible in this second activity

Answer (score 0):

You should have sent the image source to the new activity like this-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity2.this, activity1.class);
intent.putExtra("image_src", "your image source here");
startActivity(intent);
```

And receive this from next activity like this-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String easyPuzzle = intent.getExtras().getString("image_src");
```

More is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android).

And then change the source of your image in that page's view (XML) like [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974862/changing-imageview-source).

But using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) is more useful for this purpose.

This tutorial may help u-

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-ui-workshop-build-an-interactive-quiz-app--mobile-14208

Comment: What would you say by "change the source of your image.."

Comment: Please see updated answer, think u can have your answer

Comment: @AmidouFlorianTouré this answer gives a good idea of how you can use it in your case. I think you want to change the visibility of the `ImageView`, it is not difficult. Just use the idea provided in the answer.