# Convert Int to ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is some code:

```
public class Article {
(...)
private static int[] sImages =  { R.drawable.ic_picture};
private ImageView mImage;
public Article(int a)
{
    mImage = sImages[a];
}
```

In: 
`mImage = sImages[a];` 
There is this error:

> Incompatible types
>   Required: android.wiget.ImageView
>   Found: Int

How to convert int to android.widget.ImageView  or something like this?

(I create RecyclerView and in that is a lot of ImageView and i want to have List with Images to these ImageViews.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why you want to convert int to ImageView?

Comment: Try to work harder while asking questions. Take a minute to correct your grammar and spelling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing ImageView source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974862/changing-imageview-source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setImageResource`. When you call ur Article class, also pass the view.

```
private static int[] sImages =  { R.drawable.ic_picture};
private ImageView mImage;
public Article(int a,  View view)
{
    mImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    mImage.setImageResource(sImages[a]);
}
```

Comment: Wait, i tested it.

Comment: It's working, but It's some code of MainActivity:                                             for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
            articles.add(new Article(i));

Comment: Would not recommend using `setImageResource` since it decodes the `bitmap` on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list you have to write a RecyclerAdapter class to hold and set items of list.

see this: 
[Using lists and grids in Android with RecylerView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code block shows an `Article` class that is supposed to be attached to the `RecyclerView` with a corresponding image, is what I assume from your question. 
In your comments you have

`for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) { articles.add(new Article(i))}`

1. You set 30 as a hard coded limit instead you should set it to the size of your image id array.
2. You're aware that you're incrementing your index before you add the article which will cause you to lose out on the id at index 0.
3. All this does is pass an `int` through your constructor to grab the id at that array index in your `Article class` you should not have a `static` array of images in an object class.

Change your `Article` class to look like this:

```
public class Article {
    ...
    int imageID;
    public Article(int imageID) {
        this.imageID = imageID;
    }
    public int getImageID() {
        return imageID;
    }
   ...
}
```

Now when you loop through and add your articles it should like like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageIDArray.length; i++) {
    articles.add(new Article(imageIDArray[i]);
}
```

Now you're setting the `imageID` to be whatever value is in your `imageIDArray` once you're in the `onBindViewHolder()` method of your `RecyclerView` you can then easily set the correct image by using

`setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, article(i).getImageID));`