# Image button onclick change image

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android studio. I don't know much about Android Studio and Java but I'm trying to learn it.

My question is:
Is there any way to change image of image button and picture at the same time when the image button is clicked like it's in the picture i have attached?

Thank you so much!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogxDs.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQCl6.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing ImageView source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974862/changing-imageview-source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You just need to listen for Click Event and change the image using
>   `setImageResource()`

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_change);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_image);
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a ImageView and a ImageButton. You want to change the image of imageView when you press the button and at the same time change the image of ImageButton.

```
ImageView myImageView = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
ImageButton myImageButton = findViewById(R.id.my_image_button);
myImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_imageview_image);
            myImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_imagebutton_image);
        }
    });
```

Set a flag if you don't want to change after clicking second time.