# Have a lot of problems with my android app

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax-error

**Hey, I am looking to make a android app, but i got a sh!t ton of errors. I am new to Kotlin and dont know anything about these errors. Here is the code:**

```
package com.farder.inc.zortosinstaller

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button

button = b
Imageview img
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        b.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                img.set.ImageResource(R.mipmap.amogus)
            }
            )
    }
}
```

**Please Help!**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's a lot going on here, for example you're mixing Java code inside a Kotlin file (`@Override ...`). I recommend looking up some tutorials for absolute beginners to Kotlin for Android rather than posting a chunk of code and hoping someone will fix it.

Comment: well all the beginner videos use java but.. ill try! or maybe ill just swich to java

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should move these 2 lines to be inside the main class

```
button = b
Imageview img // and change Imageview to ImageView
```

This line doesn't do what you want it to `img.set.ImageResource(R.mipmap.amogus)`
This question and answers will help you with that [Changing ImageView source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974862/changing-imageview-source)

After that, if you still have errors you should post a new question and state what they are

Comment: Umm.... what is a "Main class"? And thats how you know i am a beginner ;)

Comment: The main class starts with this line. 'class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {'. If you move those 2 lines directly below that you will be inside the main (and only) class

Comment: i did it and holy macaroni, i had 21 errors and now there are 28! 5 errors are saying execpting member declaration and some other errors that i cant find. maybe thaey are new expecting a new top member declaration error (there are 5 of them).